# Can you use Azure availability set without load balancer

Tags: azure, redundancy

Is there any point in using availability sets without having a load balancer in front to distribute the traffic. As per my understanding for availability sets you will then have several VM's distributed across fault/update domains, but then you also need the distribute the traffic to these VM's correct?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Availability Sets you are improving your application high availability and SLA's to have same VM in different datacenters. You need a way to balance traffic between them to achieve this so the short answer is NO.